# custom date filter in Angular.js to change the date format

Tags: javascript, angularjs

i have a date `"endDate": "2014-11-30 01:00:00.0",` like this in json  i want to show it as **30 Nov 2014**

i tried

```
{{ phone.endDate  | date:'medium' }}
```

in html .

But still showing it as 2014-11-30 01:00:00.0

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need a custom filter if you don't want to convert your string to date in your controller:

```
app.filter('myDateFilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  return function(date) {
     var convertedDate = new Date(date);
     return $filter('date')(convertedDate, 'dd MMM yyyy');
  }

}]);
```

Comment: I used {{theDate | myDateFilter }} but its returning NaN undefined 0Nan

Comment: set a breakpoint inside the function and that the value of date and convertedDate.

Comment: plz explain in detail

Comment: Write `console.log(date)` and `console.log(convertedDate)` inside the filter function to see if it's being executed and what are those values when it does.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/):

```
$scope.now = moment(new Date()).format('DD MMM YYYY');
```

Comment: Why to use 3d party if angular provides good date formatting?

Comment: any solution without 3rd party ?

Answer (score 0):

found solution by the help of above answer . so here is code

```
 phonecatApp.filter('myDateFilter', ['$filter', function($filter) {
  return function(date) {
    // console.log(date);
     var VendDate = date.split(" ");
    // console.log(VendDate);
     var endDate = VendDate[0].split("-");
    // console.log(endDate);
     var convertedDate = new Date(endDate[0],endDate[1],endDate[2]);
     return $filter('date')(convertedDate, 'dd MMM yyyy');
  }

}]);
```